# Redirect to a page given a form submission

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form below displayed on /parties and would like to take whatever a user inputs in this form and add it to the url. I.e. if they searched for "hello" they would be redirected to parties/hello

```
    <h1>Search for a Party</h1><br>
    <%= form_tag({:action => "search"}, {:method => "get"}) do %>
        <%= label_tag :q, "Enter Playlist Code:" %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
        <%= submit_tag("Find Playlist", :name => "submit") %>
    <% end %>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#redirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic would go into the PartyController.

Something like this in (syntax may be a little off):

**PartyController.rb**

```
def search
    result = params[:q]
    redirect_to '/parties/' + result
end
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense - the only problem I'm having is that when I click the submit button, it hits my "show" method instead of my "search" method

Answer (score 0):

yeenow123 gave you a right way, I just want to clarify some points.

"parties/hello" will confuse the routing with parties/:id (show action)
If you don't want to use show action, you should except this from your route.rb: parties resource or you can use show action as function which has params[:id] is your search key and keep working on this.

Comment: If I want it to hit the search method first (where it redirects) and then hit the show method (where it renders info from the database) is there a way to specify that?

Comment: I think you can override the show routing:
- remove show routing from route.rb
- replace it with search action as parties/:query => :search
- run show method inside search action by using: render, redirect_to or call show method directly, it's up to you and your logic.